# SQL Server : Wrong Enconding on Select with Union

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got multiple tables, all of the same structure, containing the same columns. The columns are all `varchar(250)`.

Now I have a query, that connects all the tables via `UNION ALL` and selects a column named `InsertX` that contains values like "134,856710602534"

My problem is: after `UNION`ing all the tables and selecting the `InsertX` column `134,856710602534` becomes `134¸856710602534`. So the comma gets messed up. I tried different commands like `CAST (InsertX AS varchar(250))` and `Collate Latin1_General_CI_AS` in the `SELECT` query, but nothing helps.

Comment: what is the encoding of the columns, and the table?

Comment: Multiple tables with the same structure is usually a sign of a bad design - that part of the *data* has instead been embedded in the table *names*. E.g. having `MaleEmployees` and `FemaleEmployees` tables is almost certainly incorrect.

Comment: I know that its a very bad table design and also I would have made it with nvarchar. But the tables are created and used by a third party application and I have to deal with them like they are :(

Comment: If I get it right the encoding of the table is Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: No collation that I know of messes up commas. Also, SQL Server never changes collations implicitly. The UNION is not the problem. You have bad data, or bad code somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the third-party-application...
Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is the raw SQL that is converting that vs what is consuming it?  I created the following text and it still has commas:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE (
    COL1 VARCHAR(250)
);

DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE (
    COL1 VARCHAR(250)
);

INSERT INTO @tbl1
        ( COL1 )
VALUES  ( '134,856710602534'  -- COL1 - varchar(250)
          )

INSERT INTO @tbl2
        ( COL1 )
VALUES  ( '134,856710602874'  -- COL1 - varchar(250)
          );

SELECT COL1
FROM @tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1
FROM @tbl2
```